# How to setup PostgreSQL Binary path for PostgreSQL 14

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am reading up on this tutorial: PostgreSQL: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149169/binary-path-in-the-pgadmin-preferences

To setup PostgreSQL Binary path, I looked at my Preferences on PgAdmin and I see all versions of PostgreSQL to update Binary path except for PostgreSQL 14 which i am actually using.

Please where exactly should I update the Binary path to?

I have added a screenshot

[image]

Comment: It's likely not in a released version yet. https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin4.git;a=commit;h=522a92586aefce69e043cfab1fa4004fe25c0516

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Utility file not found. Please configure the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544583/utility-file-not-found-please-configure-the-binary-path-in-the-preferences-dial)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this. It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who is googling this problem out of frustration. Don't worry. The problem is `pgAdmin` does not fully support postgresql version 14 as of now (Nov 16). It happened to me as well when I tried to import/export into database.
Go to  `File > Preferences > Paths > Binary Paths > PostgreSQL Binary Path` 
You won't see PostgreSQL 14. It is ok. Just browse and set your postres 14's `bin` folder path to `PostgreSQL 13`'s `Binary Path`. Lastly, make it default by clicking on the radio button on the left. Save it and run it again.

Your problem will go away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the original screenshot, it looks like a Mac interface. So if you're on Mac, you could set PostgreSQL 13 as default, and use the path /Library/Applications/PostgreSQL/14/bin/.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone for any reason needs the path for linux/ubuntu

```
/usr/bin
```