# Utility file not found. Please configure the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

So I am setting up PostgreSQL on my PC by following Jose Portilla's Course on Udemy and when I had to restore a database by the name of dvdrental. It showed up the message

```
`Please configure the PostgreSQL Binary Path in the Preferences dialog.
```

What am I supposed to do now? Any and All Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I had the same problem, I leave you the steps

1. Click Files -> preferences -> Binary path
2. ProgresSQL Binary path: c:\Program Files\PostgresSQL\13\bin
3. Click right DataBase-> Restore...

NOTE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cBkXKCY4Ew

Comment: This was helpful, thabks Francisco.

Answer (score 39):

### **2023 Update...**

Add the path of the ***bin*** folder of PostgreSQL. For example:  `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin`

[image: For postgre]

[image]

Comment: This works. Make sure to set as default.

Answer (score 3):

1. For PostgreSQL 15, go to `file>preferences>paths>binary paths`.
2. Under EDB Advanced Server Binary Path, set EDB Advanced Server 15 to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin`
3. And under PostgreSQL Binary Path, set PostgreSQL 15 to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin` and set this as default.

for video guidance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=219xC6Zhpls

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the, "Somethig went wrong" after clicking the Binary Paths Tab, Restart Your pgAdmin.