# Utility file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

Tags: pgadmin-4

When I try to restore or backup/database from PGadmin it shows "**Utility file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog**" I have set up the binary path though.

[My Binary Path Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur9dM.png)

Here is a screenshot of my binary path setup which is validated.

Comment: I was having the same issue today, this answer helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544583/please-configure-the-postgresql-binary-path-in-the-preferences-dialog

Comment: I have set up the binary path following the answer but it's showing the same message whenever I try to restore and backup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Utility file not found. Please configure the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544583/utility-file-not-found-please-configure-the-binary-path-in-the-preferences-dial)

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly setup the Binary Path. The only issue is that you just have to give path till bin folder.
Just remove the '' after bin in your path and save it. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this would be to; go into the menu and click on "files".
**files** -> **preferences** -> **Binary paths** (under paths) -> (ignore the first EDB path table) Under the **PostgreSQL Binary Path** -> paste the path link of your PostgreSQL **bin folder**.

**Bin folder**: Go to local disk c -> program files -> PostgreSQL -> 15(your version)-> bin.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

**CHALLENGE:**

I was unable to load my sql database with the error below:
**Utility file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog**

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution to this challenge from the link below from @KaustuvPokharel

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137359/utility-file-not-found-please-correct-the-binary-path-in-the-preferences-dialog][1]

You can directly chat me up for further support